# Removing horizontal "banding" in images

Tags: python, image-processing, noise-reduction

I'm currently working on JWST data, which has some quite severe horizontal banding (see left of attached image). This is 1/f noise, present on a number of scales. Unfortunately, there's also a lot of real emission that we care about here (galaxy), so what we've been doing is fitting a noise model to a high-pass filtered version of the image. This works pretty well (see right of attached image), but highlights the fact there's noise on large-scales that we're filtering out in the high-pass filter. What I need is something that can pick up on this horizontal noise, without being affected by the real emission present in the image

[Left: raw image; right: destripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxAjD.jpg)

I've tried things like doing a sigma-clipped row median (this is biased by the presence of the real emission in the image), stacking other tiles we have (this works to some extent, but occasionally the banding is consistent between different frames of the observation so it remains in the image). I've been having a look in the Fourier plane, but got nowhere there.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! I feel like the answer may lie in some ML/advanced image processing algorithm, but I'm not well-versed in either of these things

[Edit]: Apologies, the image doesn't appear in text. I need 10 reputation points to post the image so it has to remain a link

[Edit2]: For the individual images in .fits format, I've uploaded to a Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XBQU76TLpm6dEEZu0BRvp43pEKistxm9?usp=sharing. The easiest way to get at the data is through astropy:

```
from astropy.io import fits

hdu = fits.open('filename.fits')
data = hdu['SCI'].data
```

Comment: I think it's probably generally appreciated if you present your unprocessed and processed images *separately* so that folks can easily try applying their own processing ideas... rather than having to separate them and hope that merging them didn't cause any new artefacts to be introduced.

Comment: @MarkSetchell just edited the original post. The files are .fits so these are screengrabs from a visualisation tool, the full image data is much too large for imgur

Comment: You can use a link to Google Drive or Dropbox.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Done, and a code snippet to get at the image data for those who might not have worked with fits files before